# Eclipse - Find and replace in xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, replace

i wonder how you can find and replace with Eclipse in this kind of xml

```
<row INSEE City Code="citycode" CityName="" phone="0123456789" ></row>
```

each City Code ="01234" (with any code) by an empty string. Thanks

Comment: Easiest approach would be to write a script and parse it with xpath?

Comment: For me, easiest approach was to use Find/Replace tool in Eclipse. I just have a grammar problem but i will try to parse it myself so. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Find/Replace dialog, under Options, check **Regular expressions**, and replace

```
City Code=".*?"
```

with an empty string. You can read more about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).